# Can't request to ASP.NET mvc action when using AngularJS Routeprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've the issue with angular route provider.
In app.js route config:

```
fmApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
   templateUrl: 'staticViews/home.html,
   controller: 'fmController'
 }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
})
```

and in my web.config, I rewrite url to redirect all request to index.html:

```
</system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite Url to layout.html">
          <match url=".*\.html|css/|img/|js/|data/|lib/|templates/|favicon.ico" negate="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="layout.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

In index.html I've a form when it submit i want it request to **action on server side** using $http

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    $http({
      method:'post',
      url: '/api/test',
      data: JSON.stringify(
        angular.copy($scope.data)
      )
    })
}
```

My issue is when i request to /api/test it not call to server side (api-controller and test-action) it call to layout.html (because i rewrite in web.config). If i not `rewrite url in web.config` and using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` will appear # in my url ex: http://localhost/#!/....

Comment: Have you got any console error.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but looks like your API isn't included in the rewrite negate.  Maybe try ".*\.html|api/|css/|img/|js/|data/|lib/|templates/|favicon.ico" possibly?

Comment: @Dillon Wow!! That work perfectly. Thank you alot!

Comment: @vantrung1408 Glad to hear!  I've added this solution as an answer so that you can mark the question as resolved.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but looks like your API isn't included in the rewrite negate. Maybe try

```
<match url=".*\.html|api/|css/|img/|js/|data/|lib/|templates/|favicon.i‌​co" negate="true" />
```

possibly?